# Is it possible to use p:cellEditor inside a p:columns tag?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a primefaces dataTable that gets its columns dynamically and I would like its cells to be editable using the primefaces cellEditor as show [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableCellEditing.jsf).

I tried doing it

```
<p:dataTable id="mqTable" value="#{backingBean.columns}"
                var="cols">
<p:columns value="#{cols}" var="col" columnIndexVar="colIndex"
                style="width: 10px;">

<h:outputText value="#{cols.get(0).date}" rendered="#{colIndex eq 0}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{paramBean.getProperty('format.date','dd/MM/yyyy')}"/>
    </h:outputText>
<p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{cols.get(colIndex).value}" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText value="#{cols.get(colIndex).value}" style="width: 30px;" />
        </f:facet>

</p:cellEditor>

</p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

but the columns don't show up.

I also want it to start at 1 because I'll be using index 0 for a different purpose

Comment: @BalusC Right now I am able to show the values from the list, but when I click the cell, it does not turn to an input text. Unlike the one shown [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableCellEditing.jsf)

Comment: @BalusC I am facing same issue, did you face this issue or do you know the root cause?

Answer (score 2):

Add `styleClass="ui-editable-column"` like `<p:columns ...   styleClass="ui-editable-column" >`

Comment: It didn't work to me. It gives me a NullPointerException

Comment: This will not help in any way, OP is not having styling issues, he is facing functional issue.