# How to get old/new value of edited cell from p:cellEditor in p:columns of p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, tablecelleditor, dynamic-columns

I am using Primefaces 5.3, JSF 2.2 and Tomcat 8. 
After cell editing getOldValue and getNewValue return null. Why? 
Thanks in advance

xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable id="dtbl" var="data" value="#{definitionsBean.dataList}" editable="true" editMode="cell">

<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{definitionsBean.onCellEdit}" update=":frm:dtbl" />

<p:columns value="#{definitionsBean.columns}" var="column"columnIndexVar="colIndex">

<f:facet name="header">
#{column.header}
</f:facet>

<p:cellEditor>
<f:facet name="output">
<p:outputLabel id="modelOutput" value="#{data[column.property]}" />
</f:facet>

<f:facet name="input">
<p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{data[column.property]}"
                           style="width:100%" rendered="true" />
</f:facet>
</p:cellEditor>
</p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

bean:

```
  public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event){
     Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
     Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

}
```

Comment: Do you have a h:form tag around your dataTable?

Comment: Yes, I have h:form tag.

Answer (score 0):

For normal data table Change attribute value="#{data[column.property]}" to  value="#{data.property}" in p:outputLabel and p:inputText tags. and remove p:columns

check out cell editing in primefaces link

[primefaces cell edit](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml)

For Dynamic data table

[primefaces - editable dynamic table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857314/primefaces-editable-dynamic-table)

Comment: Why is this a solution? The showcase does **not** use dynamic columns, while this example does... A **major** difference in how to address the objects. See http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml

Comment: it is worked for me with normal data table. I don't worked with dynamic data table.